# what is the use of "daily" keyword in logrotate.conf

Tags: linux, cron, logrotate

I wanted to rotate logs every hour, so I placed the `logrotate` file in `/etc/cron.hourly/` directory. This `logrotate` file has following line in it.

```
/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf >/dev/null 2>&1
```

When I open `/etc/logrotate.conf` I noticed the configuration file contains `daily` keyword.

But, still `logrotate` is getting called every hour (because it is in cron.hourly directory).

So, my question is if `logrotate` is anyways getting called every hour with the use of `cron`, what is the real use of having `daily` in `logrotate.conf` file?

Answer (score 0):

It is being called every hour, and 23 times of 24 it does nothing (as it tries to split the current file by day, and all of the file is from a single day).

If you don't specify an interval, it will rotate the file every time it is run (so, once an hour).

Comment: thanks. So, if I really want to rotate logs every hour, I've to remove `daily` from `logrotatae.conf`

Comment: In such cases, what happens if the log size is more than what is specified in configuration file? Will the logs still be rotated only after a day?